# Integrate Skype with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, skype

I need to send notification to Skype ( group) from Jenkins about the Build and Deployment status.

Can any one give the step by step process for integrating Jenkins with Skype.

Skype : it is not the business for Skype

Comment: You can use the https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Skype+Plugin plugin to send a message to a particular person?

Comment: Followed that link , "Integrates Jenkins with Skype for instant messaging. Requires extra manual installation steps!!!"     what it means?.

Comment: The plugin works by having skype installed on a slave of your Jenkins setup, I found it easier to use windows, that slave will also need a "skype" label attached to it. You then login to skype on that instance. Then install the skype plugin on the jenkins instance and you should be up and running. It's a bit messy but seems to work well when I used it a few years back.